# Concat two arrays But concat is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have two arrays.**I want to concat both array values**.But here it shows me the error,

> > NewsArr.contact is not a function

My Code

```
     var GlobalNews = [];
     var CommentArray = [];

    var CommentArr = {};
    CommentArr['Comment'] = comment;
    CommentArray.push(CommentArr);   

    var NewsArr = {};
    NewsArr['NewsNo'] = $("#newsNumber").val();
    NewsArr['Desc'] = $("#desc").val();
    //GlobalNews.push(NewsArr.concat(CommentArray)); // this also not working
    GlobalNews= NewsArr.concat(CommentArray);
```

Comment: `NewsArr` is not an array, it's an object literal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: WHat are your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.merge( CommentArray, NewsArray );` to concatenate arrays:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var GlobalNews = [];
    var CommentArray = [];
    var NewsArray = [];

    var CommentArr = {};
    CommentArr['Comment'] = 'aaa';
    CommentArray.push(CommentArr);   

    var NewsArr = {};
    NewsArr['NewsNo'] = 'bbb'
    NewsArr['Desc'] = 'vvv';
    NewsArray.push(NewsArr);

    GlobalNews = $.merge( CommentArray, NewsArray );
    console.log(GlobalNews)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```